# Cyclic Galois group and field norm

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, galois-extensions

I am struggling on solving the problem related to Galois theory.

> Let $K/F$ be a cyclic Galois extension whose Galois group is generated by $\sigma$ of order $n$. Suppose that $\alpha \in K$ satisfies $N_{K/F} (\alpha)=1$. Prove that there exists $\beta \in K$ such that $\alpha = \beta / \sigma(\beta)$.

I tried to use the linear independence of characters, that is, the maps $1, \sigma, \ldots, \sigma^{n-1}$ are linearly independent.
There must exist $\gamma \in K$ such that $\delta := \sum_{i=1}^n \sigma^i(\gamma) \neq 0$ and in this case, $\delta / \sigma(\delta) = 1$.
However, I think this observation does not give me any better insight.
Any ideas or comments are welcome.

Comment: This is Hilbert's Theorem 90. You really got this as an exercise without hints?

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg Thanks for letting me know! Yes, this is a sample question for the Ph.D qualification exam and there were no hints at all.

Comment: See for example Jacobson's Basic Algebra I, pp. 297-298. The proof there uses a cocycle condition as well as linear independence of characters. Somebody has probably written it up here also. Or you can find the details on-line somewhere as Hilbert 90 is kinda famous :-)

Comment: For the same question see [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4093974/prove-hilberts-90-in-characteristic-0-using-discriminant).